# How to call a function from a class from another class in kivy Pong ball game

Tags: python, kivy, pong

I'm practicing Kivy with the PongGame code given in the tutorial. I want to know how to call a function - serve_ball2() in the class PongGame from a newly created class - PongSample. In the below code I created a class PongSample to serve the second ball once the first ball collide with the paddle.

Update : I can call the serve_ball2() from PongSample but the serve_ball2() doesn't function as intended i.e it doesn't serve the ball.

I've shared the complete code below. Thanks in advance

Pong.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty,\
    ObjectProperty
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.clock import Clock, time
from threading import Thread

class PongPaddle(Widget):
    score = NumericProperty(0)

    def bounce_ball(self, ball):
        if self.collide_widget(ball):
            vx, vy = ball.velocity
            offset = (ball.center_y - self.center_y) / (self.height / 2)
            bounced = Vector(-1 * vx, vy)
            vel = bounced * 1.1
            ball.velocity = vel.x, vel.y + offset
            PongSample().call_game()

class PongBall(Widget):
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x, velocity_y)

    def move(self):
        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos

class PongSample(Widget):
    def call_game(self):
        print 'PongSample'
        ponggame=PongGame()
        ponggame.serve_ball2()

class PongGame(Widget):
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)
    ball2 = ObjectProperty(None)
    player1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    player2 = ObjectProperty(None)

    def serve_ball(self, vel=(4, 0)):
        self.ball.center = self.center
        self.ball.velocity = vel

    def serve_ball2(self, vel=(3, 0)):  
        print 'Serve_ball2'
        self.ball2.center = self.center
        self.ball2.velocity = vel

    def serve_down(self):
        print 'Inside Serve Down'
        self.ball.center = self.center
        self.ball.velocity = Vector(4,0).rotate(-90)

    def update(self, dt):
        self.ball.move()
        self.ball2.move()

        #bounce of paddles
        self.player1.bounce_ball(self.ball)
        self.player2.bounce_ball(self.ball)

        #bounce ball off bottom or top
        if (self.ball.y < self.y) or (self.ball.top > self.top):
            self.ball.velocity_y *= -1
        if (self.ball2.y < self.y) or (self.ball2.top > self.top):
            self.ball2.velocity_y *= -1

        #went of to a side to score point?
        if self.ball.x < self.x:
            self.player2.score += 1
            self.serve_ball(vel=(4, 0))
        if self.ball.x > self.width:
            self.player1.score += 1
            self.serve_ball(vel=(-4, 0))

        if self.ball2.x < self.x:
            self.player2.score += 1
            self.serve_ball2(vel=(3, 0))
        if self.ball2.x > self.width:
            self.player1.score += 1
            self.serve_ball2(vel=(-3, 0))

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if touch.x < self.width / 3:
            self.player1.center_y = touch.y
        if touch.x > self.width - self.width / 3:
            self.player2.center_y = touch.y

class PongApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game = PongGame()
        game.serve_ball()
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1.0 / 60.0)
        return game

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PongApp().run()
```

pong.kv:

```
    #:kivy 1.8.0

<PongBall>:
    size: 50, 50 
    canvas:
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size          

<PongPaddle>:
    size: 25, 200
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos:self.pos
            size:self.size

<PongGame>:
    ball: pong_ball
    ball2: pong_ball2
    player1: player_left
    player2: player_right

    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.center_x-5, 0
            size: 10, self.height

    Label:
        font_size: 70  
        center_x: root.width / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: str(root.player1.score)

    Label:
        font_size: 70  
        center_x: root.width * 3 / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: str(root.player2.score)

    PongBall:
        id: pong_ball
        center: self.parent.center

    PongBall:
        id: pong_ball2
        center: self.parent.center

    PongPaddle:
        id: player_left
        x: root.x
        center_y: root.center_y

    PongPaddle:
        id: player_right
        x: root.width-self.width
        center_y: root.center_y
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem with what you have so far?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I can call the serve_ball2() from PongSample but the serve_ball2() doesn't function as intended i.e it doesn't serve the ball.

P.S updated the question.

Comment: ...so what does it do instead?!

Comment: @jonrsharpe the ball should move as in serve_ball() , but here nothing happens. The function get's called though.

Answer (score 1):

To use your class add `game.serve_ball2()` `to PongApp`

```
class PongApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game = PongGame()
        game.serve_ball()
        game.serve_ball2()
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1.0 / 60.0)
        return game
```

And add `self.ball2` to bounce off the paddles:

```
#bounce of paddles
self.player1.bounce_ball(self.ball)
self.player2.bounce_ball(self.ball)
self.player1.bounce_ball(self.ball2)
self.player2.bounce_ball(self.ball2)
```

Comment: But I want to call this serve_ball from another class, that's my problem. Let me know how I can call serve_ball from another class. Calling using object of PongGame did not work as shown in code above.

Comment: why do you want to add another class, you can add a second ball in pongame with a different velocity with a couple of simple changes

Comment: I want to add another class to set timer via thread to call the serve ball (For my understanding purposes). Let me know if you can tell me how to achieve it from another class.

Comment: how do you expect anything to happen when you have nothing relating to ball2 in PongApp?

Answer (score 1):

I emphasize that this seems unnecessary, and that `PongSample` itself seems like it needn't exist at all. However, to do what you asked, I believe the following should work. One thing I really don't like about this however, is that a PongSample instance is created in the kv file, without any other purpose than to serve ball2. However...

Why not define the `serve_ball2` function in the `PongSample` class instead, and pass `ball2` to it?

Example:

```
class PongSample(Widget):

    def serve_ball2(self, ball2, vel=(3,0)):
        print 'Serve ball 2'
        ball2.center = self.center
        ball2.velocity = vel
```

And in the PongGame class:

```
class PongGame(Widget):
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)
    ball2 = ObjectProperty(None)
    player1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    player2 = ObjectProperty(None)
    # add this
    sample = ObjectProperty(None)
```

Then in the kv file:

```
# add at the top

<PongSample>:
    size: self.size
    pos: self.pos

# add the below in appropriate places within the PongGame definition

PongGame:
    sample: pong_sample

    PongSample:
        id: pong_sample # now it's linked to 'sample' in PongGame
```

So now in `PongGame` you can call `self.sample.serve_ball2(ball2)` from any method.