# Calling Function in a Different Class Through Kivy Button

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to call a function on button press in kivy, that is located in a different class screen than the button is located in. I tried running the function in the app class as well and ran into issues there. Here is the class where the function I am trying to call lies:

```
# Main screen with button layout
class LandingScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LandingScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.buttons = [] # add references to all buttons here
        Clock.schedule_once(self._finish_init)

    def ChangePic(self):
        self.buttons[1].background_normal = 'folder.png'
```

And here is the button that I am trying to call it with:

```
<InputScreen@Screen>:
    name: 'input_sc'
    FloatLayout:
        size: 800, 480
        id: anchor_1
        Label: 
            text: "What would you like to bind to this button?"
            size_hint: (1,.15)
            text_size: self.size
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.11, 'top': 1}
            font_size: 28
            font_name: 'Montserrat-Bold.ttf'
        Button:
            root: 'landing_sc'
            id: filebutton
            size: 150, 150
            size_hint: None, None
            background_normal: 'folder.png'
            background_down: 'opacity.png'
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.11, 'top': .7}
            on_release: 
                root.manager.transition = FadeTransition()
                root.manager.transition.duration = 1.5
                app.MakeFolder()
                root.IfFolder()
                root.ChangeToSlide()
```

What do I have to prefix ChangePic() with in order to call it from this location?

Alternatively- is there a way to easily work with the buttons inside of the LandingScreen class from inside of the InputScreen class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a variable in your App Class:

```
some_variable = LandingScreen()
```

and then in your button call ChangePic() like this:

```
on_release: app.some_variable.ChangePic()
```

Also, this can help you: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24424962/how-to-call-a-function-from-a-class-from-another-class-in-kivy-pong-ball-game), [Kivy's Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kivy-users/8Af1UoHUiIY), [Introduction to properties](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/events.html#introduction-to-properties)

Comment: Would this variable need to be created inside of a method or no? I am getting an error if I don't put it inside one, and that app.variable cannot find it if I put it inside of one?

Comment: The variable which reference LandingScreen() need to be created inside of your App Class:
`class AppClass:
    some_variable = LandingScreen() 

    def MakeFolder(self):
        #your code here`

So, some_variables has the methods of LandingScreen().
You can call whatever method of LandingScreen() using "some_variable" inside of AppClass() just doing some_variable.ChangePic()

But, you want to call ChangePic() from your kv, so you need to put app.some_variable.ChangePic()

Is the same that you do with app.MakeFolder() in your kv but, with ChangePic() you need to use some_variable